# How to split array into sub-arrays and display items using Leitner System?

Tags: arraylist, sub-array

I need to write a Flashcard program using Leitner System. I am stuck where I want to show a card from a random array.

I can add cards to an arraylist and then randomly show the cards. Then I added more arrays and attempted to show a card randomly from the arrays.

This is the code I used to randomly select a card from one array.

```
          int s = deck.getBox1().size();
          int deckIndex = LeitnerSystem.randInt(s);

textArea.setText(deck.getBox1().get(deckIndex).getFront());
```

I know how to randomly select a box and randomly find a card within that box, but how I replace the "getBox1()" so that this method still work? Please let me know if there is a better way to implement this. Thanks!

p.s. I tried to use Box(i) to replace Box1 so that I can generate a random int i but java does not allow an array name with "()".

Answer (score 0):

I finally used if/else to get this. It doesn't look like a smart way but seems work:)

I have another question: if I have multiple arrays running, is there a way to find out where an item is from (array name and index)? So that I can move the item to another array according to button click (correct/wrong).

Thanks again!